# Access .aspx div from .ascx using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dom, web-controls

I am developing an ASP.NET 4.0 webforms application in VS 2010.

I have an .aspx page (A.aspx) with a web control (A.ascx) on it.

Now A.aspx has a div with id="divToggle". I want to be able to use jquery to access the "divToggle" from within A.ascx. I tried using $('#divToggle') and $.find('#divToggle') but both return null. I have no trouble accessing elements this way on the same control/page.

Is there a way I can access A.aspx's "divToggle" from A.ascx in jquery?

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Comment: Does your JS code run after the document ready event? $(document).ready(function () { /* your code here */ });

Comment: It sounds a little janky to have a control that will only work properly if the page that included it has specific ID in it. You'll have to guarantee that any page that ever uses that control will have the div. The guy who inherits your project will likely hate this.

Comment: Bart, I am using the AJAX function pageLoad(); @Mike - it's ok cause this control will only ever be on this page or others with the same div...

Answer (score 1):

Where does the script code get added to the page? If you can't find the element, then the script code is run before the element gets added to the DOM. Try putting the code into [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    // code
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I am not using document.ready but I am using "function pageLoad()" as my page is making certain AJAX calls and for this reason I had to use pageLoad. Would that make a difference?

Comment: Hmm, then you're using MS Ajax with jQuery. Also I just noticed that you said "both return null", and jQuery will return an object even when there aren't any elements that match the selector. Your $ might be getting redefined somewhere (although MS Ajax by itself won't conflict). Try using `jQuery(<selector>)` instead of `$()` and see if that works.

Comment: Also, is `$('#divToggle')` actually executing and returning null or are you getting a reference error in the console?